# How can I get info about the computers devices?

Tags: kernel, libraries

I've been looking for way to obtain the system info, e.g. total memory, number of processor, hard drive free space etc.. asking the kernel for that info, how do I manage to do that from c++, without using .system calls or system_info structures, via kernel.dlls perhaps?.. I found a lot of info but using system calls, I need to get the system info but not using a created library, more like create my own asking the kernel for that info.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch If you post these types of comments, please tell the OP that their question *can* be automatically moved there if the community decides to, and that **they should not re-post** it. Normally, the community will see that this involves programming and users will vote to close anyway, so there's hardly any benefit from "this should be on XYZ.SE" comments. Cheers!

Comment: @slhck: ack, will do so in the future

Answer (score 0):

I know you said "without `SYSTEM_INFO` structures", but I think the [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is exactly what you want.

From [Getting Hardware Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

    void main()
    {
       SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;

       // Copy the hardware information to the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

       GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo); 

       // Display the contents of the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

       printf("Hardware information: \n");  
       printf("  OEM ID: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwOemId);
       printf("  Number of processors: %u\n", 
          siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors); 
       printf("  Page size: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwPageSize); 
       printf("  Processor type: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwProcessorType); 
       printf("  Minimum application address: %lx\n", 
          siSysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress); 
       printf("  Maximum application address: %lx\n", 
          siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress); 
       printf("  Active processor mask: %u\n", 
          siSysInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask); 
    }
```

The docs for `GetSystemInfo` spefically indicate that it's in `Kernel32.dll` - I think the buck stops here.